# Use token to login - cypress does not redirect

Tags: javascript, authentication, cypress

Cypress logs correctly using POST method but does not redirect to the webpage after login. Stays on the login page. Even if I force it by     "cy.visit('web/')"
stays on the login 
"cy.get('button')" 
finds button on the login page - not page that should display after login

commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {

    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/admin-api/login',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
            username: Cypress.env('correctUsername'),
            password: Cypress.env('correctPassword'),
        },
        retryOnStatusCodeFailure: 463
    })
    .then((resp) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', resp.body.user.token)
    })
})
```

---

```
describe('login using token', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login()
    })

    it('visit web', () => {
        cy.visit('web/')
        cy.get('button')
    })
})
```

Comment: are you sure that `jwt` token stores inside localStorage? If so, this is not good. Usually, it stores inside cookies. If you want to set a new cookie with token use `document.cookie`

Comment: I checked app again and yes, you are correct - token is stored inside cookie. In header Set-Cookie. So code should look like this?    .then((resp) => {
        document.cookie.setItem('jwt', resp.body.user.token)
    })

Comment: ```.then(resp => { document.cookie = `jwt=${resp.body.user.token}` })```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. I check cookie after cy.login () using the method         cy.getCookie('AuthTokenName')
and a proper cookie is stored. Any ideas what is still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I checked token from the cookie that I get using method above and it is active - I managed to use it in this website using Postman. However, the described problem still exists.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
    Cypress.log({
      name: 'loginViaAuth0'
    })


return cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
            url: '/admin-api/login',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: {
                username: Cypress.env('correctUsername'),
                password: Cypress.env('correctPassword'),
                disposableToken: 1111,
            },
            retryOnStatusCodeFailure: 463
         })
         .then((resp) => {
            document.cookie = `AuthUser=${resp.body.accessToken}` 
         })
})
```

Test itself:

```
describe('login using token/cookie', () => {

        it('should successfully log into our app', () => {
          cy.login()
            .then(() => {
              cy.visit('web')
            })
            debugger
        });
})
```